# I can't call a mixin function inside a javascript function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-mixin

i'm working on a small project using nuxt.js and right now i have created a plugin using mixin as you can see, but i don't know why function b doesn't work inside render function :

```
import Vue from 'vue'


Vue.mixin({
  methods: {

    a () {
      const render = function () {
        this.b()
      }
      render()
    },

    b () {
      alert('testme')
    }

  }
})
```

Comment: in your render function - are you sure "this" is what you expect it to be?

Comment: i want just to call b function i don't know how :(

Comment: Use an arrow function to define `render`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you used the `function` keyword to define `render` the `this` therein refers to the calling context (`a`) which has no property b.

The solution is to use an arrow function: `const render = () => this.b();`.

```js
const methods = {

  a() {
    const render = () => {
      this.b()
    }
    render()
  },

  b() {
    alert('testme')
  }

}

methods.a()
```